# Schema errors after restoring a table

Tags: google-bigquery

Has anyone encountered schema issues after restoring a previously overwritten (deleted) table in BQ?

A few months ago I overwrote a table by mistake and restored it using the undelete (cp@time) function.   The data was restored but the schema came back corrupted to the point that the data is unusable.  For example, I have a company ID column that was originally loaded into bq as a string.  The field is a set of numbers and if I let BQ auto define the schema that field would've been an integer.  Since this was an ID i manually loaded it as a string.  After the undelete anytime I try to run a query involving this field I get an error:

Type mismatch for column 'Company_ID' in table 'log.428001'. Expected type 'int64', actual type 'string' in file :mdb=cloud-dataengine.

It seems like the underlying data is a string as it always was but the schema somehow is expecting an Int64.  Support and I have tried all sorts of exports, cast's, and copies to somehow get this data out in the hopes of re-importing correctly.  Thus far nothing has worked.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: Please file a bug on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B). Make sure to include the project ID/dataset/table name in your report.

Comment: Hi Elliot.  Thanks for your note.  Support told me they did in fact open an issue for me.  I've been chatting with them for a few months which is why i thought i'd try my luck here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like when you overwrote the table, the schema is changed from string to integer. When you copy the deleted data out, it's copied with the integer schema, even though the data has the field as string. You can try correct it by overwrote your new table again, changing the schema back to string. Then, restore/copy the again-deleted data using time decorator. Now the final table will have both data and schema with type string.

Comment: Hello Hua. Thank for your note.  When you say "overwrote your new table again" do you mean to literally delete the table for a second time?

Comment: Yes, assuming by delete you mean overwrite the table and give it a new schema, using cp/query/load, like "bq query --replace --destination_table=table 'SELECT ...'".

Comment: Hi Hua-  Amazingly support replied the day after you posted your msg with a similar solution.  I copied the corrupted to a new dataset, replaced it with dummy variables (strings) thus corrected the schema, deleted it, and then restored it.   When the data returned it followed the correct schema!  wow.  Within a few hours I had restored over 2 TB of data and I'm finally back in business.  Thank you so much for the help!  :)